# Share network printer on the lowest network

Tags: networking, router, printing

Here's the setup:

```
MODEM
  |
ROUTER 1
WAN IP: (INTERNET), LAN IP: 192.168.1.1
-> PC1 192.168.1.100
-> PC2 192.168.1.101
  |
ROUTER 2
WAN IP: 192.168.1.254, LAN IP: 192.168.2.1
-> PC3 192.168.2.100
-> PC4 192.168.2.101
  |
ROUTER 3
WAN IP: 192.168.2.254, LAN IP: 192.168.3.1
-> PC5 192.168.3.100
-> PC6 192.168.3.101
-> PRINTER 192.168.3.102
```

`PC5` and `PC6` can print to `PRINTER` fine, since the printer is on the same network, however, I need to be able to print to the printer from `PC3` and `PC4` -- I don't care about PC1 and PC2. If `PRINTER` was plugged into `ROUTER 2`, that wouldn't be a problem, however, the printer is connected to `ROUTER 3` and there is no way around it.

What are my options in enabling `PC3` and `PC4` to print to `PRINTER`? Some kind of routing? Or can I put `ROUTER 2` and `ROUTER 3` on the same network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a static route to router 2 that tell it that the network 192.168.3.0/24 is behind 192.168.2.254. Now, if Router 3 is performing NAT (network address translation) you will need to forward the appropriate ports from the WAN interface to the printer.

Comment: and if you do happen to want full routing later on, you'll need to tell router 1 that both 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 are behind router 2. I would also disable address translation on router's 2 and 3, eventually.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the static route.  On router 2, under static route, I have to populate the following fields: destination, subnet mask, gateway, and hop count. Would the destination be 192.168.3.102, subnet 255.255.255.0, and gateway 192.168.2.254?

Comment: if you use the EXACT ip of the printer, then you would use type in 192.168.3.102 subnet mask 255.255.255.255 gateway 192.168.2.254. If you want to be able to access any device behind router 3 you would add the network like I suggested above by typing in 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.2.254.